# Single tab and browser window authentication with microsoft.identity.web using blazor server

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-web

Hi I have a blazor server application which is working fine with authentication to aad using microsoft.identity.web using the following basic implementation...

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

The thing I am trying to achieve (and am completely lost to find any details on) is how to make this application authenticate just for the current session (i.e. only the current tab and not multiple tabs in a browser or on tabs in different instances of the same browser or after closing a browser and reopening it).

I cannot seem to find much useful reference for using microsoft.identity.web then than the most basic implementations.

Any help much appreciated.